# Why does this toggle checkbox function work in jQuery 1.3.2 but not in 1.6.2?

Tags: jquery, css

This code simply toggles checkboxes and adjusts text box css.  By default, the text box is readonly, then when you click the checkbox it should adjust the readonly and highlight the text box.

The following code works fine in 1.3.2, but doesn't do anything in 1.6.2.  Has something changed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleAll").click(function() {
        var $checkBoxes = $("input:checkbox.closeItem");
        $checkBoxes.attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));

       $("input:checkbox.closeItem").each(function() {
            HandleCheckboxCheck($(this));
        });
    });

    $("input:checkbox.closeItem").click(function() {
        HandleCheckboxCheck($(this));
     });

});
function HandleCheckboxCheck($check) {
    var $trackingNumber = $check.parent().siblings("td.trackingNumber").children(0);
        if ($check.attr("checked") == true) {
            $check.attr("checked", true);
            $trackingNumber.addClass("highlight");
            $trackingNumber.removeAttr("readonly");
            $trackingNumber.val("");
        } else {
            $check.attr("checked", false);
            $trackingNumber.removeClass("highlight");
            $trackingNumber.attr("readonly", "readonly");
            $trackingNumber.val("Check to Enable");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you set `$check.attr("checked", true)` when you *just* confirmed that it is already `true`? Likewise with setting it to false.

Comment: I get your point, but like I said the above code works as-is in 1.3.2, but simply does nothing in 1.6.2. I don't get an error message, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: So now your title contains information which directly conflicts with the body of the question. Does the code work in jQuery 1.3.2, or in 1.6.2?

Comment: It works in 1.3.2, before the changes to .attr()

Comment: Yes, it works in older versions, just not newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.prop is the proper way to toggle checkboxes.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

The behavior of .attr is covered in this section:

$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6)    "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6.1+) "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state
$(elem).attr("checked")(pre-1.6)    true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state

Comment: .prop is the proper way to toggle checkboxes in 1.6+, which was part of the question

Comment: Go to the link. Nearly the entire discussion of the .prop() method involves checkboxes.

Comment: @BNL. This does not answer the question at all. S/he asks why the existing code does not work in 1.3.2.

Comment: q: "What is the correct way to toggle checkboxes [...] in jQuery 1.6.2 vs. 1.3.2?" a: "Prop"

Comment: His title is misleading but if you read the question itself, you realize the intention was not the more straightforward interpretation of the title.

Comment: I have adjusted the title.  Sorry.

Comment: q: "Has something changed?" a: "Prop" :) Everything different between prop and attr for 1.3.2 vs 1.6 vs 1.6.1+ is covered in the link in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I will look at the link you sent.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery 1.6.2, testing `.attr('checked')` for a checkbox returns "checked" or `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/wkDgv/5/

In jQuery 1.3.2, it returns `true` or `false`: http://jsfiddle.net/wkDgv/4/

Your sample code asks `if ($check.attr("checked") == true)` -- which never occurs in jQuery 1.6.2.  http://jsfiddle.net/wkDgv/6/

However, if you replaced that code with just `if ($check.attr("checked"))`, you should get identical results.

Comment: If he is already changing the code, he should change it to prop which actually returns true/false instead of .attr("checked") which doesn't (directly at least).

Comment: .attr('checked') doesn't look like it works in 1.6.3.  http://jsfiddle.net/VJAZT/1/